# batch generating PDF files with R markdown or other methods?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have the following dataset:

```
Name Score
Amy    A   
Bob    B
Charlie C
```

I want to generate three PDF files:

First one: Amy.pdf, with the content "Amy, your score for MATH 101 is A."

Second one: Bob.pdf, with the content "Bob, your score for MATH 101 is B."

Third one: Charlie.pdf, with the content "Charlie, your score for MATH 101 is C."

Is there a simple to way to do this with only one R or R markdown file? There are hundreds of individuals in the actual dataset.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create it as a graphic and export it as a pdf:

**Data**:

```r
d <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Amy", "Bob", 
"Charlie"), class = "factor"), Score = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

**Perform operation**:

```r
for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
  pdf(file = paste0(d[i, "Name"], ".pdf"))
  plot(0:1, 1:0, bty = "n", type = "n", axes = F, xlab = "", ylab = "")
  text(.5, .5, paste0(d[i, "Name"], ", your score for MATH 101 is ", d[i, "Score"]))
  dev.off()
}
```